# Spring data Specification match/ filter cast numeric column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am using Spring Datas `Specification` to implement data filtering. I am new to Spring Datas `Specification` and still trying to understand how it works.

I am stuck with two use cases:

1. filter on the numeric column with match mode contains.
2. filter on the numeric column with match mode contains.

Is it possible to cast the data column to string and then use like operator?

Something like  `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(phone AS VARCHAR(9)) LIKE '%0203'`

Or maybe there is some other Spring Data magic I can use?

```
public Predicate toPredicate(
        final Root<Model> root,
        final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
        final CriteriaBuilder builder)
    {
        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        
        final Map<String, FilterMeta> map = filters.getFilterBy();
        for (final Entry<String, FilterMeta> entry : map.entrySet())
        {

            if (!ignoreList.contains(entry.getKey()))
            {
                final Class<?> fieldType =
                    ReflectionUtils.findField(Model.class, entry.getKey()).getType();
                if (fieldType.equals(LocalDateTime.class))
                {
                       //how to query LocalDateTime countains mode
                }
                if (fieldType.equals(int.class))
                {
               //how to query int with countains mode
                    predicates.add(builder.like(root.get(entry.getKey()), "%" + entry.getValue().getValue() + "%"));
                }
                if (fieldType.equals(String.class))
                {
                    predicates.add(builder.like(root.get(entry.getKey()), "%" + entry.getValue().getValue() + "%"));
                }

            }
        }

        return builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
```

I get the following exception when using the specification above.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%0%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
```

Comment: You can invoke SQL functions with the Criteria API. This question contains an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820415/jpa-criteria-api-query-with-sql-function-call-which-takes-parameters Also note that Spring Data JPAs Specification uses JPAs Criteria API, so that is what you need to search for.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.persistence.criteria.Expression.as` methond did the magic
you can cast to any datatype

```
predicates.add(builder.or(
builder.like(root.get(columnName).as(String.class), "%" + filterValue + "%")));
```